# Excluding "sudo " from shell history

Tags: zsh, command-history

I thought it might be a good idea to exclude `sudo` at the
beginning of commands from shell history, to prevent deleterious
mistypes.  I would do this with a cronjob and sed, but was
wondering if there were a more correct way of doing it (in zsh)?

PS to comments: Yes, maybe simply removing "sudo " is not so good.  But isn't it a bit troublesome that something like `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb` could be executed with `<c-r>d<cr>`?  Maybe it would be a good idea to remove the "s", so that one would have to supply `<c-a>s`.

Comment: You could defang or omit them via something like http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312528/zsh-history-comment-out-dangerous-commands

Comment: I personally prefer not to exclude any command, so i can autocomplete the command quickly by Page up/down.

Comment: I prefer to be capable of auditing what I do.

Comment: Just to add another idea: if you’re concerned accidentally re-running a sudo command, ensure you have the PASSWD flag, and run `sudo -k` after the dangerous command (and think before you enter your password). Alternatively, disable the password caching with timestamp_timeout.